# Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ that is relatively prime to $|G|$. Show that $a \rightarrow a^n$ is automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $n$ be a positive integer that is relatively prime to $|G|$.  Show that the mapping $a \rightarrow a^n$ is an automorphism of G.

I've proven everything except for one-to-one-ness.  I start with $a^n = b^n$ but I've made no progress with showing that $a=b$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^n = b^n$ gives $(ab^{-1})^n = e$. Recall that if $x^p = e$, then $|x|$ is a divisor of $p$. Hence $|ab^{-1}|$ is a divisor of $n$. By Lagrange's theorem, it is also a divisor of $|G|$. Hence, it is a common divisor of $n$ and $|G|$, so $|ab^{-1}| = 1$ and so $ab^{-1} = e$.

Comment: But how can $|ab^{-1}|$ divide $|G|$ if $n$ and $|G|$ are coprime?

Comment: @OliverG why should that be a problem? In fact this is what I used to conclude that $|ab^{-1}| = 1$ (hence that $ab^{-1} = e$)

Comment: By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element divides the order of the group. Therefore $|ab^{-1}| = n$ should divide $|G|$ but since gcd$(n, |G|) = 1$, $n$ doesn't divide $|G|$?

Comment: @OliverG I hope that the edit clarifies things.

Answer (score 9):

Since $n$ is coprime to $|G|$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $nm\equiv 1$ (mod $|G|$). Hence if $a^n=b^n$, then
$$ a=a^{nm}=(a^n)^m=(b^n)^m=b^{nm}=b $$
so the map is injective.

Comment: Nice, +1. Alternatively, if the OP knows Lagrange's theorem, the kernel of $a \mapsto a^{n}$ is the set of elements of order dividing $n$ in $G$, which is the identity only, since the order of any element must also divide $|G|$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a\in\ker f$, where $f(x)=x^n$. Then $a^n=1$. On the other hand, there are integers $r$ and $s$ such that $1=rn+|G|s$.

Then
$$
a=a^{rn+|G|s}=(a^n)^r\,(a^{|G|})^s=1
$$

Therefore $f$ is injective. Surjectivity is implied by injectivity because $G$ is finite.