# Prove that mapping $\phi : x \to x^m $ is automorphism of group G where $|G|=n$ and is relatively prime to m $\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that mapping $\phi : x \to x^m $ is automorphism of group G where $|G|=n$ and is relatively prime to $m \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

**Attempt**

To show $\phi$ is 1-1. So take $x^m=y^m$ implies $x=y$. How do I use $(m,n)=1$ condition? I am new to this and my instructor hasn't been helpful. Please can you give me full solution. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876283. Your group is not assumed to be abelian, right? You also have to check that $\phi$ is a group homomoprhism.

Comment: @Watson Not abelian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ that is relatively prime to $|G|$. Show that $a \rightarrow a^n$ is automorphism.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876283/let-g-be-a-finite-abelian-group-and-let-n-in-bbb-z-that-is-relatively-pr)

Comment: @Watson How it is duplicate?

Comment: @Jeff : the question I linked was asking : "I start with $a^n = b^n$ but I've made no progress with showing that $a=b$.", which is very similar to your question, in my opinion.

Comment: Moreover this is wrong if $G$ is not abelian, cf $G=S_3$, $m=6,n=5$, if $\phi : x \mapsto x^5 = x^{-1}$ were a morphism, then $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ i.e. $ab=ba$ for all $a,b \in S_3$…

Answer (score 2):

$$(m,n)=1\implies am+bn=1\;,\;\;\text{for some integers}\;\;a,b,\implies$$

$$x=x^{am+bn}=(x^m)^a(x^n)^b=(y^m)^a\cdot\overbrace{ 1}^{=(y^n)^b}=y^{ma}y^{nb}=y^{ma+nb}=y$$

Yet if the group isn't abelian the map you give may not a homomorphism...

Comment: i have got it. you want to prove that if images are same so is elements. But why $y^n=1$

Comment: @J.Deff That's true for *any* finite group: the order of any element in a group is always a divisor of the group's order. This is Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. i am confused

Comment: @J.Deff This is  the most elementary, basic of group theory: have you heard of Lagrange's Theorem? Otherwise this exercise isn't for you