# What is the role of $\gcd(n,|G|) = 1$ in the following question?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ that is relatively prime to $|G|$. Show that $a \rightarrow a^n$ is automorphism.

The above question has been asked here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876283/let-g-be-a-finite-abelian-group-and-let-n-in-bbb-z-that-is-relatively-pr)

All the answers for proving one-one make use of the fact $\gcd(n,|G|) = 1$. Can we not simply take log and solve this:

$$\begin{align}
n \log a = n \log b  &\implies \log a = \log b \\
&\implies a = b? 
\end{align}$$

What is the purpose of $\gcd(n,|G|) = 1$?

Comment: $\log(\text{a rotational symmetry of a line}) =? $

Comment: You certainly can't just "simply take log." What kind of an object is $\log a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm is a function from real numbers to real numbers. You can't just feed it elements of some arbitrary group without doing some work to try to define what it means first.

Comment: There is a notion of complex logarithm.

Comment: Oh Right! I wasn't thinking beyond real numbers! We could done that if the element of the group were real numbers! Right?

Comment: @ngbtwby Still no. *If* all the elements of $G$ are real numbers *and* the group operation in $G$ is real number multiplication *and* they're all positive *then* you can take logarithms as you describe. But the only groups with this property are infinite or trivial, so the question is meaningless :(